# Combine all tiff images into one single image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-stitching, python-imageio

I have 15 tiles or tiff files a folder and I would like combine it as a single file with all the images as one tiff image. All the tiles should be stitched as a single tiff image. How do I do that?

What I tried so far?

```
import imageio
import os

path = "path/to/dir"
image_path_list = os.listdir(path)

with imageio.get_writer("new_image.tif") as new_image:
    for image_path in image_path_list:
        image = imageio.imread(path+image_path)
        new_image.append_data(image)
```

This saves as a separate image in a tiff file. I would like to stitch all the images together and save it like the following:

[image: Desired Output]

1,2,3...,15 represent  the tiles. Needs to be stitched as a single image.

Comment: Does all images have identical dimensions (width and height)?

Comment: @Daweo Yes, all the images have identical dimensions

Comment: You can just do it in your Terminal with **ImageMagick**, no need for Python `magick montage -tile 3x -geometry +0+0 image{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}.tif BigBoy.tif`

Comment: you can use Image.paste() in pillow see: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=paste()#PIL.Image.Image.paste, first you create an empty image of right size then paste each of your image inside it

Comment: @Mark Setchell I get the following error if I use ImageMagick```such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
montage:  'BigBoy.tiff' @ error/montage.c/MontageImageCommand/1806.```  How do I solve this?

Comment: How are you images named?

Comment: @Mark Setchell  the images are named the following: ```09A, 09B, 09C, ...``` etc. All are tiff images

Comment: Try `magick mogrify -geometry +0+0 -tile 3x 09*tif result.tif`

Comment: Mark Setchell I get the following error: ```mogrify: unable to open image '3x': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
mogrify: unable to open image 'result.tif': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
mogrify: unable to open image 'result.tif': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.```

Comment: Not sure what's going on. Let's try something simpler. `magick montage 09* result.tif`

Comment: You aren't on Windows are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given one directory with 15 images of same size

using PIL (pillow), I ended up with:

```
from PIL import Image


import os

path_to_file ='tiff-files'


images = []



for i in os.listdir(path_to_file):
    with Image.open(path_to_file+'/'+i) as im:
        images.append(im.copy())

    
new_image = Image.new(images[0].mode, (images[0].size[0]*3,images[0].size[1]*5))



new_image.paste(images[0])
new_image.paste(images[1],(images[0].size[0]*1,0))
new_image.paste(images[2],(images[0].size[0]*2,0))
new_image.paste(images[3],(0,images[0].size[1]*1))
new_image.paste(images[4],(images[0].size[0]*1,images[0].size[1]*1))
new_image.paste(images[5],(images[0].size[0]*2,images[0].size[1]*1))
new_image.paste(images[6],(0,images[0].size[1]*2))
new_image.paste(images[7],(images[0].size[0]*1,images[0].size[1]*2))
new_image.paste(images[8],(images[0].size[0]*2,images[0].size[1]*2))
new_image.paste(images[9],(0,images[0].size[1]*3))
new_image.paste(images[10],(images[0].size[0]*1,images[0].size[1]*3))
new_image.paste(images[11],(images[0].size[0]*2,images[0].size[1]*3))
new_image.paste(images[12],(0,images[0].size[1]*4))
new_image.paste(images[13],(images[0].size[0]*1,images[0].size[1]*4))
new_image.paste(images[14],(images[0].size[0]*2,images[0].size[1]*4))

new_image.show()
```

let me know if it works.....

After Mark Setchell suggestion here a new version, hope it is better

```
from PIL import Image
import os

path_to_file ='tiff-files'



def stich_tile(path_to_file, xx , yy):
    images = []
    for i in os.listdir(path_to_file):
            images.append(i)

    
    if len(images) >= xx*yy:
        pass
    
    else:
        raise ValueError('not enough images in path_to_file !!!!!!!!!!!')
        
    
    sq_x = xx
    sq_y = yy
    img_x = (Image.open(path_to_file+'/'+images[0]).size[0])
    img_y = (Image.open(path_to_file+'/'+images[0]).size[1])
    img_mode = (Image.open(path_to_file+'/'+images[0]).mode)
    
    new_image = Image.new(img_mode, (img_x*sq_x, img_y*sq_y))
    
    x = 0
    y = 0
    cnt = 0
    for i in images:
        with Image.open(path_to_file+'/'+i) as img:
            new_image.paste(img, (x,y))
            cnt += 1
            x += img_x 
            if cnt == sq_x:
                x = 0
                y += img_y
                cnt = 0
            else:
                pass
                
  
    return new_image
 

stich_tile(path_to_file, 3, 5).show()
```

And  thinking more along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468658/2836621

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

# path_to_file ='tiff-files'

path_to_file ='tiff-files2'

# path_to_file ='tiff-files3'



    

image = []
for i in os.listdir(path_to_file):
    with Image.open(path_to_file+'/'+i) as im:
        image.append(im.copy()) 
        
     


w, h = image[0].size



new_image = np.zeros((4 * h, 3 * w)).astype('uint8')


col = 0
row = -1
for i, img in enumerate(image):
    if not i % 3 :
        row += 1
        col = 0
    img = np.array(img)
    new_image[row * h: (row + 1) * h, col * w: (col + 1) * w] = img
    col += 1




image_pillow = Image.fromarray(new_image, mode = 'L')

image_pillow.save('prova.tif', mode = 'L')


image_pillow.show()
```

tested with .tif images grayscale 8-bit

modify adding 3 channel for RGB et similia:

`new_image = np.zeros((3 * h, 3 * w,3)).astype('uint8')`

`new_image[row * h: (row + 1) * h,col * w: (col + 1) * w,:] = img`

once more the last example as function for 8 bit grayscale images:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

path_to_file ='tiff-files'

# path_to_file ='tiff-files2'

# path_to_file ='tiff-files3'

# path_to_file ='tiff-files5'

    
def stich_img(path_to_file, x , y):

    image = []
    for i in os.listdir(path_to_file):
            image.append(path_to_file+'/'+i)
    
    print(image)
         
    if len(image) >= x*y:
        pass
    
    else:
        # raise ValueError('not enough images in path_to_file !!!!!!!!!!!')
        raise ValueError('EXCEPTION not enough images in path_to_file !!!!!!!!!!!', x*y ,'images  needed : ', len(image),'images present !!!')
    
    
    image = image[:x*y] #-----> riduce lista immagini al numero richiesto
    
    
    with Image.open(image[0]) as img0:
        w, h = img0.size
   
    
    
    
    # new_image = np.zeros((4 * h, 3 * w)).astype('uint8')
    new_image = np.zeros((y * h, x * w)).astype('uint8')
    
    
     
    col = 0
    row = -1
    for i, imgs in enumerate(image):
        with Image.open(imgs) as img:
            if not i % x :
                row += 1
                col = 0
            img = np.array(img)
            new_image[row * h: (row + 1) * h, col * w: (col + 1) * w] = img
            col += 1
            
    

    
    image_pillow = Image.fromarray(new_image, mode = 'L')
    
    return image_pillow

img_stiched = stich_img(path_to_file, 3,5)   

# img_stiched.save('prova.tif', mode = 'L')


img_stiched.show()
```

Comment: Rather than loading all 15 images unnecessarily into memory at once, you would probably do better to load them one at a time and halve the demand on RAM. Also, rather than do 15 repetitive `paste()` calls inline like that, you would do better in a loop, where you just added the width and height as the x and y increment for each iteration.

Comment: from here: 'https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=14991' :  ImageMagick allocates a number of your images in memory until memory is exhausted and then places the rest on your SSD.  .... not sure if it still valid

Comment: I wasn't talking about ImageMagick, that is an entirely different proposition based very much on  *ease of use*, i.e. a single line command in Terminal and no coding knowledge required. I was suggesting that if you plan to go to the trouble of learning, writing and using Python, you can do a lot better than write code that hogs memory and is repetitive, hard to maintain and inflexible in its implementation.

Comment: I already started to figure out how to implement your suggestions. One question why images.append(im) instead of images.append(im.copy()) in my code produce a list of images that cannot be shown using .show() ? errors says missing attribute but have size and mode ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell is it better now ?

Comment: I was thinking more along these lines... https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468658/2836621

Comment: Can’t figure out what the first : is for in ‘new_image[:, row * h: (row + 1) * h, col * w: (col + 1) * w] = img’  , I’ll try with numpy too .  Should it be faster than using image.paste for very big puzzles??

Comment: @MarkSetchell added the https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468658/2836621 suggested mode . Is it what was expected ?

Comment: @pippo1980 that really helps thanks! But, when I stitch the images I get extra blank tiles added after images 3, 6,9,12,15. How do I remove that?

Comment: which script are you talking about 1st 2nd or 3rd ? for 3rd one you need to adjust this line: new_image = np.zeros((4 * h, 3 * w)).astype('uint8')   with (5* h, 3*w) to match your example

Comment: 3rd one uses pillow instead of imageio, pillow does swap x and y axes when passing it to numpy array with: img_numpy = numpy.array(imge_opened_with_pillow_Image.open)

Comment: @disukumo added stich(path_to_file, x , y) version of last script

Comment: @pippo1980 I was talking about the first script

Comment: Sorry, it was the one with stich_tile(path_to_file, xx , yy). It was very much helpful for me. But, I don't know how to remove the black tiles that were added to the image while stitching.

Comment: @disukumo tried it with my test panel of images both showing and savit it  I don't have any extra tiles ?? I'll think about it talking about first script

Comment: @pippo1980 no I don't have extra tile. But, I tried to save the stitched image using stich_tile(path_to_file, 3, 5).save('filename.tiff'). Could that be a problem?

Comment: @disukumo use pippo = stich_tile(path_to_file, 3, 5)   [run func] ---

pippo.show()  [show image returned by func ] ----

pippo.save('2nd_script_15_img.tiff') -- [save image] --   but your one work the same

Answer (score 4):

It seems from your comments that you are prepared to consider a non-Python solution, so I used **ImageMagick** in the Terminal to montage 15 images as follows:

```
magick montage -tile 3x -geometry +0+0 09*tif result.tif
```

[image]

To demonstrate how you can lay out 5 images across instead of 3, add a different background and affect the horizontal and vertical spacing differently, here is a variation:

```
magick montage -background magenta -tile 5x -geometry +5+15 09*tif result.tif
```

[image]

---

Just FYI, I made the 15 randomly coloured blocks like this:

```
for x in {a..o} ; do magick xc: +noise random -scale 80x50\! 09$x.tif ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Read all images in a list. Iterate over this list using two nested for loops. One in range of 3 and one in range of 5. Use `numpy.hstack()` and `numpy.vstack()` to make a final 3x5 image assuming that the size of each tile image is same.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy:
This script accepts generator of images (to work faster with large images). It does not check their size in advance. If image height does not fit row height or if rows have not the same width, it will fail.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
from imageio import imread, imwrite
from pathlib import Path


def tile_images(images, cols):
    """Tile images of same size to grid with given number of columns.
    
    Args:
        images (collection of ndarrays)
        cols (int): number of colums 
    
    Returns:
        ndarray: stitched image
    """
    images = iter(images)
    first = True
    rows = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        
        try:
            im = next(images)
            print(f"add image, shape: {im.shape}, type: {im.dtype}")
        except StopIteration:
            if first:
                break
            else:
                im = np.zeros_like(im)  # black background
                
        if first:
            row = im  # start next row
            first = False  
        else:    
            row = np.concatenate((row, im), axis=1)  # append to row
            
        i += 1
        if not i % cols:
            print(f"row done, shape: {row.shape}")
            rows.append(row) # finished row
            first = True
            
    tiled = np.concatenate(rows)   # stitch rows    
    return tiled        

def main():
    images = (imread(f) for f in Path().glob("*.*") if f.suffix in (".jpg", ".png") if f.name != "new.png") 
    new = tile_images(images, cols=3)
    imwrite("new.png", new)


def test():
    im1 = np.arange(65536).reshape(256,256)
    im2 = np.arange(65536/2).reshape(128,256)
    
    images = [im1,im1,im1,im2,im2,im2]
    
    # works
    new = tile_images(images, 3)
    imwrite("new.png", new)
    
    # failes
    new = tile_images(images, 2)
    imwrite("new2.png", new)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    # test()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, I get the following error. ```ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 776 and the array at index 1 has size 5000``` How do I solve it?

Comment: Make sure all images in folder are of same size. This script doesn't care. It accepts generator of images, so it is faster, but it does not check the size of images in advance. It tries to stitch files and if height of images in one row differ or if width of rows differ, it will fail. I excluded "new.png" form image list, maybe this was the image with differnent size.

Answer (score 0):

The following elaborates on @saad_saeed answer.

Note, the following will break:

1. if your `list_of_images` doesn't have enough images to build the `num_mosaic_rows x num_mosaic_cols` mosaic.  I've left it to the user to add the handling of this (e.g. adding an `if/else`).
2. if each img in your `list_of_images` doesn't have the same shape

   ```
   def build_mosaic(list_of_images, num_mosaic_rows, num_mosaic_cols):

       list_of_mosaic_rows = []

       for row_number in range(num_mosaic_rows):

           list_of_mosaic_rows = list_of_images[row_number*num_mosaic_cols,(row_number+1)*num_mosaic_cols]

       mosaic = np.vstack(list_of_mosaic_rows)

       return mosaic
   ```